# How to build and maintain a library for multiple languages?

Tags: java, python, c++, perl

I need to implement a library which will be called from multiple languages - Java, Python, Perl and possibly more in the future. I'd hate to implement (and maintain) the same thing again and again in multiple languages.

One option I can think of is to write the core functionality in C/C++ and use SWIG to generate bindings for target languages; or maybe write the bindings myself.

Thre are some reasons why it can't be an independent service.

Are there any other mature alternatives? I am looking for options to compare before I settle for one.

Ideally, I'd like to do it using a source to source compiler or a source code generator. But I can't find one that supports all of the above languages - with potential for future additions.

I may consider any alternative binding generators if they provide any advantages over SWIG.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: This question, while reasonable in general, is inappropriate on Stack Overflow. We don't really do conversational items here and your question is looking for a strategic conversation rather than a tactical solution.

Comment: In general working out what you need the library to do, determining what to test and fixing bugs takes most of the time. If you spend most of your time just writing code non-stop you are in a very unusual situation.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: No, I don't write code non stop. The reason I don't want to reimplement it in multiple languages is to avoid code duplication. Duplicate code often means library behaviour differing in subtle ways or having subtle bugs.

Comment: @mah: Sorry, I didn't think about that angle while asking this question, I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: @Darkstar to some degree different language favour different styles of API, but I take your point that you only want differences if you intended them, not by accident.

Comment: Sort of an answer comment here...in addition to your standard RESTful API options over HTTP, I've had success in the past orchestrating dissimilar backend apps via Protobuf for serialization and Redis for inter-process communication. If there isn't a Protobuf library for your language of choice you can always fall back on a more basic serialization format like JSON.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to write the library in C with a simple API.  Every non-obscure language has some way to interface with C code.

Depending on the style of the API, SWIG can save some time in generating the bindings; but unless it's very big and regular, you might find it easier to write the bindings by hand.

Some Languages (at least Python in your question) have an FFI mechanism, that lets you write the whole binding in the target language, making it much easier to deploy and maintain.  Note that most of those are focused on C APIs, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you plan on access the library, is it possible to expose the public API via Web Services?

This way you can write the shared module in any language and access it via a common protocol such as a RESTfull web service.

Look at Microservices architecture.

Comment: There are certain restrictions due to which it can't be a RESTful service.